# Remote model annotation refreshes page on success

Tags: asp.net-core

**Model Class**

```
    [Remote(
        "isExaminationTemplateInUse",
        "GENExaminationTemplate",
        AdditionalFields = "ExaminationTemplateID",
        ErrorMessage = "Template Name already exists.",
        HttpMethod = "POST"
    )]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Template Name is required.")]
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public String ExaminationTemplateName { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("isExaminationTemplateInUse")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> isExaminationTemplateInUse(String ExaminationTemplateName, int ExaminationTemplateID)
    {
        return Json(true);
    }
```

**AJAX Part**

```
        //Submit Main Form.
        $(document.body).on("submit", "#mainForm", function (event) {
            //Prevent Default Region.
            event.preventDefault();


            //Post Region. 
            //Serialize the form datas.   
            $.ajax({
                url: '/GENExaminationTemplate/SetExaminationTemplate',
                type: "post",
                async: true,
                data: { pstrJSONMasterData: jsonMasterData },
                success: function (response) {
                    window.location.href = response;
                }
            });
        });
```

- Add New Record Mode, Works Fine. Reason: In this mode focus moves through the field and on submit it does not go for validation.
- **Edit Record Mode, Not Works Fine.** Reason: Focus not moves through the field, On click of submit button system moves into action "isExaminationTemplateInUse" and on line "return Json(true);" refreshes page, that moves to page load function rather page save function. However, by just passing focus through the field that is using [Remote], system works fine.

In scripts section following file references are also present on top of the page.

jquery.js,jquery.validate.js, jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

Comment: Can you post the related code in the SetExaminationTemplate action method and the Add New Record Post action method? I have created  a sample using your code, it seems that in the Add New Mode, after entering values for the remote validation field, it will trigger the remote validation function, then, in the ajax success function, it will refresh the page via the `location.href` property. But in the Edit mode, if not focus on the remote validation field, it will ignore the remote validation function, and submit the form data to the correct action method.

Comment: "isExaminationTemplateInUse" action is called on click of "Submit", its not using ajax called to submit the page. On completion of "isExaminationTemplateInUse" action my page get refresh and ajax call to submit get lost due to page refersh.

Comment: `its not calling ajax called on submit`, Try to set break point in the submit function and check whether the Ajax method is called, and if there have any error message (Using F12 developer tools to check it)? Besides, you could also set a break point in the Ajax success function or add an error function to check if the Ajax function executed success or have any error?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried with breakpoints in c# code and also tried debugger in ajax. there is no error in the code according to the system. Problem is " return Json(true);" line of code that refreshes page. :(